# Can't insert data into the database in Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet::_place()

Tags: database, model, sql

folks.
Help me please. How can i get information about all authorize.net failed transactions and save it to the db?
I'm trying to do it like this.
Make rewrite of Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet::_place().
Create in this method custom Mage::dispatchEvent and pass to observer response result data.

But for some reasons i can't save this data to database in my observer. Even direct sql query not working.

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$table = $resource->getTableName('maymodyle/my_table');
$query = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`customer_name`, `error_id`, `authorize_message``) VALUES ('TestFname TestFLname', '3', 'This transaction cannot be accepted.')";
$writeConnection->query($query);
```

But in my controller or helper this code work just fine.
Any idea why?

Comment: Did you get solution of this. I am also facing same issue.